# Ink Jet Printing Onto Foil Already Transferred to Paper

Tags: paper, printing, foil

My first question here...

I'm trying to print "magical" cards from my PNP game and I want to use a home technique that resembles (in-line) cold foil.

1. Equipment:

   - Black only laser printer ($119.99)
   - 12" Hot press laminator ($36.99)
   - 6-color Ink Jet Printer ($449.99)
   - Metal Straight-edge and X-acto knife
   - 1/16" Corner Rounder
2. Materials:

   - Laser Toner
   - 320 gsm white card stock 8.5" x 11" sheets
   - Silver Heat Transfer Foil Roll 12" x 200' (gives me aprox. 282 pages)
   - Inkaid Clear Matte Coating for Ink Jet printing (this is what I want to replace)
   - Clear Matte Fixing Spray
   - Black Sharpie
3. Method I've Worked Out:

   - Using the laser printer, I print on the card stock the spots where I want foil on the 8-up 2.5" x 3.5" Game Cards and 4-up Location cards.
   - I then put 8." x 11" sheet of the transfer foil on top of the laser-printed sheet and put the two in the laminating sleeve
   - I run the package through the Laminating Machine and the silver foil sticks to the spots of printed laser toner
   - I then have to spread a coating to allow for ink jet printing using some kind of brush (but it's not recommended for plastic or film)
   - Allow 24 hrs drying
   - Spray with Artists' Fixing spray to fix the ink jet ink to the foil.
   - Another 24 hrs drying.
   - Cut cards to size and round corners
   - Use sharpie on card edges in case I've accidentally beveled an edge

So here's my question:

**Is there an aerosol spray alternative to the Inkaide coating that will adhere to the silver film (that won't bead up), that I can then ink jet print onto?** I don't know what kind of coating current ink jet foil sheet makers use, and they want to keep it a "trade secret".

Years ago I would print these cards on full sheets of Papilion shiny silver that after drying, fixing, and drying again, I would peal off the backing and adhere it to the card stock, making the complete card face foiled. A few crafting companies offer the same kind of sheets, but don't offer shiny foil. The fixing spray I would use with Papilion still allowed the foil to appear shiny even though the fixing spray was technically "matte". (BTW - Papilion is out of business. Used to be able to get the sheets at my local Dick Blick store)

Back then, cold foil (in-line) printing was on these massive Gutenburg printing modules. This consists of two modules - First a UV-Fixed Glue printer, and then the foil transfer - that are added in before the individual C, M, Y, and K printing and then (usually) a UV fixed gloss surfacing module. This would result in a seven-module printing press. I had business cards batched printed by this place in Florida with a set press setup. The only other available in the US at the time was in San Jose, CA.

Games like "Magic the Gathering" still use an opaque white ink over pre-laminated foiled paper, then CMYK to get the the partially foiled effect.

Now, a few places offer on-demand inline foil using a desktop digital foil printer ($1K), but they will only do the back of cards as it's only one image multiplied. They won't do the faces as each card has unique artwork. (And they charge a sh*t load of money for the service.)

Can anybody please help me? Again, I'm looking for a clear spray the will adhere to the foil and not bead up.

Thanks in advance.

Jim